# What do the numbers 1 to 9 mean on my thermostat?

Tags: heating, thermostat

What do the numbers translate to in temperatures?

[image]

Comment: How long has it been since Britain went metric? Could the numbers be Fahrenheit  temperatures with the zeros removed?

Comment: They don't. It's essentially 0-100% of whatever heating or cooling capacity your system offers. Since you've told us nothing about it, I can't say anything more. Please revise with useful information.

Comment: The answer given here in comments is correct - they are just relative numbers like on a stereo system volume control.  This one can't be turned up to 11, I see.  ;-) .

Answer (score 4):

It means it is a cheap device and they are not willing to provide a properly calibrated thermostat at that price point.

Instead they are giving you a real thermostat, but with no effort to calibrate it to any real world values, just slap a knob on it and done.  You are meant to turn it up if you are too cold and down if you're too hot, iteratively, until you find the temperature that suits you.  Then you are to remember that you like it at 3-1/2.

Since the knob is just slapped on, expect two identical units to have different meanings of, say, "5" .

Comment: I've seen these before - your description is perfect. What I haven't yet figured out is similar controls in a refrigerator - numbers - or even letters (just looked at one - numbers for the refrigerator, letters for the freezer (both controls inside the refrigerator section)) with "Warmer" and "Colder" with no clear indication whether "Warmer" (or "Colder") means turn the knob in that direction (like a thermostat) or that the numbers/letters in that direction "mean" warmer/colder (in which case turn it the other way) - about the worst User Interface on a non-computer device that I've ever seen.